# Multiple AND conditions in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, multiple-conditions

I've got an Oracle table CUST with Fields YEAR and STATUS. I'm trying to write a statement that will select the records where ((CUST.YEAR = '2017' and CUST.STATUS = 'ACTIVE') and where (CUST.YEAR = '2018' and CUST.STATUS = 'ACTIVE')).  When both of these statements are true, I want to return '1' else '0'

```
select *
from cust
where cust.year = '2017' and cust.status = 'Active'
```

returns the correct number of rows (394).

```
select *
from cust
where cust.year = '2018' and cust.status = 'Active'
```

returns the correct number of rows (451).

Here's where the wheels fall off (due to my inexperience with SQL scripting).  I've tried to combine the two select statements and I either gets tens of thousands of rows or errors because of incorrect syntax.  This is before even attempting to use a case statement to return a comparative result (if both of these conditions, then '1' else '0').

I realize this is probably pretty elementary stuff but the syntax is beyond me as of now.  Would someone be kind enough to help me construct this statement?

The few times I've posted to this forum I've learned things that help to make me more self-sufficient, so I offer my thanks in advance.

Comment: *I've tried to combine the two select statements...* what did you try?

Comment: And as for your `CASE` statement: `SELECT CASE WHEN cust.year IN ('2017', '2018') and cust.status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, cust.year, cust.status, cust.whatever...`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood it, `or` might be what you're looking for, i.e.

```
select *
from cust
where (cust.year = '2017' and cust.status = 'Active')
   or (cust.year = '2018' and cust.status = 'Active');
```

which - as William says - leads to

```
where cust.status = 'Active'
  and cust.year in ('2017', '2018')
```

Comment: `and cust.status = 'Active'` is common to both, though, so it's crying out for another refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `IN` here:

```
select *
from cust
where cust.year IN ('2017', '2018') and
      cust.status = 'Active'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly you want to determine whether your table has records for both pairs of conditions, that is , whether you have active records for both 2017 and 2018. The solutions provided so far will assert whether *either* condition is true but not both.

So here is a solution which satisfies your actual requirement. We have a WITH clause which selects one active record for each year (which is all your need). The inline view then counts how many records it found. If the count is two then you have active records for both years.

```
with tst as (
    select cust.cust_id, cust.year
    from   cust
    where  cust.year   = '2017'
    and    cust.status = 'Active' 
    group by cust.cust_id, cust.year
    union  all
    select cust.cust_id, cust.year
    from   cust
    where  cust.year   = '2018'
    and    cust.status = 'Active' 
    group by cust.cust_id, cust.year
)
select cust_id
       , case when cnt = 2 then 1 else 0 end as your_condition
from ( select cust_id, count(*) as cnt
       from tst
       group by cust_id )
/
```

Comment: you are right on the money, I want to select if the table has records for both pairs of conditions (but thank you to the other respondents who have planted the idea that I shouldn't repeat the cust.status = 'Active' if I were using an IN statement for an OR condition).  So now my issue is that output returns only a single row for the case statement (showing '1' -- both conditions were met), but only in a single row.  I expected 200+ rows showing either '1' or '0' (Yes or No), perhaps using another field/column cust.cust_id to identify which customers is a '1' or '0'?  -- Thanks.,

Comment: APC's script successfully compares both conditions but what I need my output to show is rows for all of the customers with columns for both the cust_id and the comparison value ('1' or '0').  I reviewed my original question and I completely dropped the ball and failed to mention that the output should show all of the roughly 2000 records with cust_id and the Comparative Condition.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to ask is whether the WITH clause can be inserted into a longer selection query?

Comment: Not to ask another really naive question (being pretty new to this forum) but would one typically go back and choose Edit below the original question and in essence overwrite what I'd previously posted as the background and question, or instead tack additional info on to the end(s) of the original question?  I don't want to have a lot of hate associated with my handle because I'm not familiar with the normal conventions/protocols.  I like to play be the rules. Thanks.

Comment: Editing questions to make them better - clearer, more focused, etc - is positively encouraged. Don't worry about "hate". StackOverflow is actually a pretty friendly place and surprising non-toxic compared to other corners of the web. It's true not everybody perceives it that way but like a lot of online communities complexity brings forth emergent behaviour [which it is easy to misinterpret](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/).

Comment: I will try to clarify my thoughts and recompose the original post.  Ms.Chipps is spot-on regarding the timidness and insecurity that people feel when asking a community with much more collective expertise than beginners who have to do elementary coding because everyone else at work thinks 'I.T' all means the same thing and if you can do one thing well (or several things passably) that you must also be an expert coder.  I like challenges and learning new things, but the unrealistic expectation that everyone in an I.T.-related field does everything equally well can be frustrating.